# Using weblate for translating content other than software

Tags: weblate

I'm interested in translating the subtitles of a course in MIT Open Courseware to my native language. I want to do it in collaborative fashion so that it would be faster. I have found the weblate. However I'm not sure whether it's possible to use it for translations of material other than software.

Do you have any experience using weblate to translate documents that are not necessarily software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've probably already figured out, the [many subtitle formats](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html#subtitle-files) are directly supported by Weblate, so yes it's possible to translate non software projects.

Weblate can be used for localizing any kind of content - I've seen localizing projects for printed media or books as well.